# If $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = A$ then prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{f(x)} =\frac{1}{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

This is a part of my homework and I was asked to prove that if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) = A$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{A}$.

In the previous question, I was asked to show for $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) = A$, and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} g(x) = B$, $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)+g(x) = A+B$

I solved that by showing $|f(x)+g(x) - (A+B)| \le |f(x)-A| + |g(x)-B| = \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ but I am not sure if this help on this question

Comment: Make sure to include dollar sign around the equation if you want MathJax to parse it.

Comment: Thanks, it's my first post and I have corrected it

Comment: Of course we need $A\ne 0$.

Comment: That is also one assumption that we have to make I believe, before this part, I was asked to show if  $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = A$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = B$, then  $\lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x)+g(x)) = A+B$. Don't think this will be helpful for this question tho

Comment: Please show your work on the proof, too.

Comment: If you prove that f(lim g(x))=lim f(g(x)) and use the fact that 1/x  is a function then the result follows.

Comment: do you need an answer in $\varepsilon-\delta$ terms?

Comment: @janmarqz yes, we are required to do that in $\epsilon - \delta $ terms

Comment: @SebastianGarrido That is my thought to, except that $f$ needs to be a continuous function.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $A\neq0$.

Set $\epsilon>0$. We want $\left|\dfrac1{f(x)}-\dfrac1{A}\right|<\epsilon$ by making $|f(x)-A|$ as small as we please.

Now, $\left|\dfrac1{f(x)}-\dfrac1{A}\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|\dfrac{f(x)-A}{A\cdot f(x)}\right|<\epsilon$.

We can make $|f(x)-A|$ as small as we like, so that we only need to worry about $\left|\dfrac1{A\cdot f(x)}\right|$.

To bound $|A\cdot f(x)|$, make $|f(x)-A|<\dfrac{|A|}2$ which puts a lower bound on $|f(x)|$ of $\dfrac{|A|}{2}$.

Thus, $\left|\dfrac1{A\cdot f(x)}\right|<\dfrac1{|A|\cdot \left|\dfrac{A}{2}\right|}=\dfrac{2}{|A|^2}$.

Now, we can write this down formally.

Set $\epsilon>0$.

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = A$, there is some $N_0$ such that $|f(x)-A|<\min(\dfrac{|A|^2\epsilon}2,\dfrac{|A|}{2})$ for all $x>N_0$.

So, suppose $x>N_0$. Since, $|f(x)-A|<\dfrac {|A|}2$, $\dfrac{|A|}{2}<|f(x)|$.

Thus, $\left|\dfrac1{f(x)}-\dfrac1{A}\right|= \left|\dfrac{f(x)-A}{A\cdot f(x)}\right|=\dfrac{|f(x)-A|}{|A|\cdot |f(x)|}<\dfrac{\dfrac{{|A|}^2}{2}\epsilon}{|A|\cdot \dfrac{|A|}{2}}=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

The first limit says given any $\epsilon \gt 0, \;$ $\exists N \in \Bbb N  $such that $\left|f(x) - A\right| \lt \epsilon $ whenever $x \gt N$

$$\left|\frac 1 {f(x)} - \frac 1 A\right| = \left|\frac {f(x) - A} {f(x)A}\right|   $$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary.

Due to the previous limit we can find $M \in \Bbb N$ such that $\left|f(x) - A\right| \lt \frac {\epsilon} {\left|f(x)A\right|} $

Therefore, $x \gt M \implies \left|\frac 1 {f(x)} - \frac 1 A\right| \lt \epsilon$.

Given any $\epsilon \gt 0, \;$ $\exists M \in \Bbb N  $such that $\left|\frac 1 {f(x)} - \frac1 A\right| \lt \epsilon $ whener $x \gt M$

$\implies \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{A}$.

Comment: No, that was too fast. In line 4, for any *constant* $c$ you can find $M$ such that $|f(x)-A|<c$ if $x>M$. But here you are making an invalid step, using $M=\varepsilon/|f(x)A|$ which is not a constant.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: You're right. Lemme see..

Comment: @Ishfaaq: you need to bound $\frac{1}{|f(x)|}$ from above

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: Nope can't seem to come up with a bound. Sorry guys for the false answer. Should I retract the post??

Answer (score -1):

The statement is only true if $A \neq 0$. If you believe that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x =0$, then put $g(x)=1/x$ and note that $\lim 1/f(x)=\lim g(f(x))= g(\lim f(x)) = g(A)=1/A$ since $g$ is continuous at $A\neq 0$.